# Get the id of all images in a post

Tags: php, posts, images, array

Im trying to get the id of images from a post. i've tried with `wp_get_attachment_url( $id )` and some other options but always get an empty array when i do var_dump or print_r. Whats the correct way to do it? thanks.

Comment: look this function https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id

Comment: thank you but thats not what i want. ive tried that, but i want the id from all images inserted in the content of the post

Answer (score 1):

If it is post-thumbnail, it will return the ID:-

```
<?php $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ); ?>
```

try this.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i want to get the id from images inside the content. Imagine i put 4 images in that post i want to be able to access them dynamically by their id.